# Highlight gives weird results

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight

I'm working with elasticsearch and my highlight doesn't give me what I expect. My settings looks like that :

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
       "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                 "my_analyzer": {
                      "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
                      "filter": {
                           'lowercase','asciifolding'
                      }
                 }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                 "my_tokenizer": {
                      "type": "ngram",
                      "min_gram": 2,
                      "max_gram": 25,
                      "token_chars": [
                           "letter",
                           "digit"
                      ]
                 }
            }
       }
  }
}
```

I put some product in my index

```
PUT index/product/1
{
 "name" : "Kit Guirlande Guinguette 50m Transparent",
 "field2": "foo"
}

PUT index/product/2
{
 "name": "Guirlande Guinguette Blanc 20 Bulbes 10M",
  "field2": "foo"
}
```

The mapping for `name` and `field2` :

```
"name_product": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        },
        "search": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
    },
    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
},
"fields2": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
     },
     "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
},
```

And I'm doing a research :

```
GET index/product/_search
{
 "query":{
      "multi_match": {
           "query" : "guirlande gui"
           "fields":[
                'name','field2'
           ]
          "minimum_should_match" : "100%"
      }
 }
 "highlight" : {
      "fields":{
          "name.search" : {
               'highlight_query':{
                    'match':{
                         'query'=>"guirlande gui"
                    }
               }
          }
      }
 }
}
```

Response :

```
{
 "hits": {
  "total": 2,
   "hits": [
         {
               "_index":"index",
               "_type": "product",
               "_id": "1",
               "_source": {
                     "name": "Guirlande Guinguette Blanc 20 Bulbes 10M"
                },
               "highlight": {
                     "name.search": [
                           " <em>Guirlande<em> Guinguette Blanc 20 Bulbes 10M"
                     ]
               }
         },

         {
               "_index": "index",
               "_type": "product",
               "_id": "2",
               "_source": {
                     "name": "Kit Guirlande Guinguette 30m Blanche"
                },
               "highlight": {
                     "name.search": [
                           " Kit Guirlande Guinguette 30m Blanche"
                     ]
               }
         }
   ]
 }
}
```

But for the second hit in highlight I would like to have `" Kit <em>Guirlande Gui</em>nguette 30m Blanche"`. I think I have this kind of problem when the matching part is not at the beginnig but can't figure out why.

EDIT: 
I also tried to change the type of the highlight to 'unified' and it's better but still not whet I want. It gives me :

```
{
 "hits": {
  "total": 2,
   "hits": [
         {
               "_index":"index",
               "_type": "product",
               "_id": "1",
               "_source": {
                     "name": "Guirlande Guinguette Blanc 20 Bulbes 10M"
                },
               "highlight": {
                     "name": [
                           " <em>Guirlande Gui</em>nguette Blanc 20 Bulbes 10M"
                     ]
               }
         },

         {
               "_index": "index",
               "_type": "product",
               "_id": "2",
               "_source": {
                     "name": "Kit Guirlande Guinguette 30m Blanche"
                },
               "highlight": {
                     "name": [
                           " Kit<span class="highlight"> G</span><span class="highlight">u</span><span class="highlight">i</span><span class="highlight">r</span><span class="highlight">l</span><span class="highlight">a</span><span class="highlight">n</span><span class="highlight">d</span><span class="highlight">e</span><span class="highlight"> </span><span class="highlight">G</span><span class="highlight">u</span><span class="highlight">i</span>n<span class="highlight">gu</span>ett<span class="highlight">e </span>30m B<span class="highlight">la</span><span class="highlight">n</span>che"
                     ]
               }
         }
   ]
 }
 }
```

So it's not really readable so I think a picture could help :
[image]

We can see I have the right think in highlight but I also have a lot of unwanted information in highlight like "lan" and "e" in "blanche" or the second "gu" of "Guinguette"

Mapping :

[image: Mapping]

Analyzer :

[image: analyzer]

Search :

[image: search]

Comment: You test data is completely wrong: you only added the settings and we don't know what's the mapping of the `name` field and the same goes for `foo` field. Provide a valid test for someone to be able to help you. What you provided so far, even with minor modifications, doesn't return any documents.

Comment: @AndreiStefan is it better like that ?

Comment: I still think your test is not the one you are actually using. The analyzer you have there is not lowercasing the text, but in your search you use lowercase `guirlande gui` which will not match at all what you put as documents. I can try and guess what you want to achieve and if I give you a solution you'll come back and say that in whatever scenario it doesn't work etc.

Comment: In my opinion, the analyzer you are actually using for the results you are posting is not the one you defined and presented in this post. Your `my_analyzer` is not splitting the text like `guirlande gui` so it could be highlighted like that.

Comment: I used the lowercase in the nalyzer but forget to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it works now. This is my final config :

```
DELETE my_index
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 25,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            },
            "search": {
              "type": "text",
              "search_analyzer": "standard",
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my_index/product/1
{
 "name" : "Kit Guirlande Guinguette 50m Transparent",
 "field2": "foo"
}

PUT my_index/product/2
{
 "name": "Guirlande Guinguette Blanc 20 Bulbes 10M",
  "field2": "foo"
}

GET my_index/product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Guirlande Gui",
      "fields": [
        "name.search",
        "field2"
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": "100%"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "name.search": {
        "highlight_query": {
          "match": {
            "name.search": {
              "query": "Guirlande Gui"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "type" : "unified"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is how your analyzer should look like and, also, you query:

- it should have a `lowercase` filter
- it should have a second sub-field called `search` (or the name of your choice), it should have a different search analyzer and the same indexing analyzer
- the `search` sub-field should be the one used in the highlighting part with a different `highlight_query`.

```
DELETE my_index
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 25,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            },
            "search": {
              "type": "text",
              "search_analyzer": "standard",
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my_index/product/1
{
 "name" : "Kit Guirlande Guinguette 50m Transparent",
 "field2": "foo"
}

PUT my_index/product/2
{
 "name": "Guirlande Guinguette Blanc 20 Bulbes 10M",
  "field2": "foo"
}

GET my_index/product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Guirlande Gui",
      "fields": [
        "name",
        "field2"
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": "100%"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "name.search": {
        "highlight_query": {
          "match": {
            "name.search": {
              "query": "Guirlande Gui"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did what you say but still have problems. Now I have `<em>Guirlande</em> Guinguette 10M Blanche Avec Prise` and the one who start whith something else thant Guirlande stay the same. here `Kit Guirlande Guinguette 30m Blanche`. I updated my post with your ideas

Comment: I also added picture of my code just to be sure I didn't make silly mistake

Comment: I'm sorry, but it works for me. I used ES 5.6.3 and this is my complete testcase: https://gist.github.com/astefan/0aa1ec9a09738e8f61679bb740d7de9d. I suggest you perform an isolated test case with a separate small index and provide a step-by-step list of commands that you used to test this. I suggest you post your REST commands in a gist just like I did. I can test those and reproduce otherwise I don't know how I can help you further.

Comment: ok thanks for your time. I'll try to redo evrtyhing from scratch and if that's work i'll validate your answer tomorrow

Comment: I also have weirdly high score results like `197.8033`don't know if that's relevant

Comment: You were asking about the highlighting. Is the score relevant to the initial question you had?

Comment: No no But I don't know you got a score of 12, me 10 times higher I was thinking maybe there is a link between my problem and this difference

Comment: Scoring has nothing to do with the highlighting issue you have.

Comment: I found a solution. You helped a lot so i'll give the answer and give you the bounty then. Thanks mate !